# Global variables not allowed in headers?

Tags: c++, arduino, platformio

I am trying to use separate files for my PlatformIO Arduino project, but I get this error:

```
.pio/build/uno/src/test.cpp.o (symbol from plugin): In function `value':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `value'
.pio/build/uno/src/main.cpp.o (symbol from plugin):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

To me this error sounds like the one you would get if you don't have include guards or use pragma once, but they didn't solve my problem.

This is my main.cpp:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "test.hpp"

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println(value);
}

void loop() {
}
```

test.hpp:

```
#ifndef TEST_HPP
#define TEST_HPP

int value = 3;

#endif
```

The test.cpp just includes the test.hpp and does nothing else.

Comment: Side note: [Global variables are evil.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484635/are-global-variables-bad)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have two source files in your project: `main.cpp` and `test.cpp`.  Both are probably including test.hpp.  So now each source file has independently picked up a `value` variable.  So the linker gets confused because it doesn't know which `value` each module should use.  And you probably do not want multiple instances of this global variable.  You just want a single one.

Do this instead in test.hpp:

```
extern int value;
```

Then in test.cpp:

```
int value = 3;
```

Comment: It has been a while since I last programmed something bigger in pure C++ but I think I never ran into issues there. Is there something different with Arduinos C++?

Comment: Nope. This behavior was inherited from C. Hasn't changed for decades.

Comment: It's not the C++ compiler having an issue, it's the linker.  Some linkers might have command line options be able to just "pick one" if it sees multiple symbol definitions or just give a warning. But in practice, you really do not want to define variables in header files, just declare them.

Comment: Thanks for both explanations